# Incorporating JSON objects in a table into JSON output

Tags: json, sql-server

I have two tables with some data:

Table 1: A single row of data actin as header information to the data contained in table 2.

Table 2: A table with multiple rows including various data columns, but also including two columns with JSON formatted text `(varchar(max))`.

The sample data is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y1Zb2a2G-NZ71wNLQxTTeiF8gXdLuIRfUrqBVmAdTFU/edit#gid=0

The requirement is to wrap the data in Table 2 within Table 1 producing a single valid JSON output including the two columns with JSON formatted text.

I expect the output to be produced by something looking like this:

```
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT *
        FROM Table2
        FOR JSON path
        ) elements
FROM Table1
FOR JSON path
```

I am not sure what the best way is to incorporate the JSON formatted text into this output.  I suspect that one will have to use JSON_modify() to achieve this.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was actually quite simple. The statement merely requires `JSON_Query()` statements for the two columns with formatted JSON text to get the required output.

```
SELECT *,
       (
        SELECT 
SequenceID,ItemID,Description,arrow,arrowColor,Value,valueUnit,volatility,BulletChartID,JSON_Query(BulletChart) BulletChart,JSON_Query(TrendLineChart) TrendLineChart
        FROM Table2
        FOR JSON path
        ) elements
FROM Table1
FOR JSON path
```